# How to tie TeX macros to text or another macro?

Tags: macros, page-breaking, text-manipulation

Is it possible to tie a TeX macro to some text (e.g. the next paragraph) or
another macro?

For your information, here is a more specific description of the
problem:

I am using a set-up macro

```
\responsible{myname}
```

that simply puts "myname" into the footer until the command
is used again with another option. So it just expands to something like:

```
\def\responsible#1{\ifoot{#1}}
```

The problem I have is that sometimes LaTeX inserts a pagebreak
before a paragraph (or `\chapter`, `\section`, ...). Since the author's
name often changes from page to page `\responsible` must be expanded on
the same page as the corresponding text.

On the one side it is clear that, when a chapter or section command is involved,
`\responsible` could be used after the chapter command to ensure 
the correct function. On the other side this solution does not work for a text paragraph.

```
%% This works fine
\chapter{My Chapter}
\responsible{myname}

%% This:  
\responsible{myname}
example text, example text, example text.
%% or this does not work
\responsible{myname}
\chapter{My Chapter}
```

Is it possible to tie the command to the following paragraph without affecting the character or word spacing? Maybe even ~ is a possible solution, if the inserted space is somehow ignored by TeX.

For example the solution could look like:

```
\responsible{myname}\tieto example text, example text.\par
```

or even:

```
\def\responsible#1{\ifoot{#1}\tieto}
```

EDIT: MWE for the chapter/section problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Footer Package
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Clear footer and header
\clearscrheadfoot
% Define \responsible and set footer
\makeatletter
    \let\@responsible\relax
    \def\responsible#1{\gdef\@responsible{#1}}
    \ifoot{\@responsible}
\makeatother

% For test texts
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
% Set author
\responsible{My Name}
\blindtext

% Does not work 
\responsible{My Name 2}% \ignorespaces here or in the definition also does not work
\chapter{A Chapter}
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

MWE for the text/paragraph problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Footer Package
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Clear footer and header
\clearscrheadfoot
% Define \responsible and set footer
\makeatletter
    \let\@responsible\relax
    \def\responsible#1{\gdef\@responsible{#1}}
    \ifoot{\@responsible}
\makeatother

% For test texts
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
% Set author
\responsible{My Name}
\blindtext\blindtext \blindtext
\blindtext
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede.
Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat.
Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent
blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

% Does not work 
\responsible{My Name 2}% \ignorespaces here or in the definition also does not work
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\ignorespaces`?

Comment: Thanks! Did not know that macro. Nevertheless this does not seem to work for me (tested).

Comment: The `\chapter` command issues `\cleardoublepage`, so the `\responsible` command sets things that go in the ejected page. Just set `\responsible{My Name 2}` after `\chapter`.

Comment: As I wrote, there is no big problem with chapters, but what about adjacent paragraphs?

Comment: @SimonM.Laube: Please show us a example where exact this problem occurs

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: Hello. If you mean the problem with adjacent paragraphs, here is a MWE (see edited question above). I created a case were the text of page 1 exactly fits the page and the whole next paragraph is automatically put onto page 2. Even though, the second `\responsible` macro executes on page 1.

Comment: If you have three different paragraphs by three different people on a page, which author should be printed in the foot?

Comment: Well, in this case I would put something like
`\responsible{name 1, name 2}` on top of a page. For the MWEs we have to assume that the author's name changes exactly at the pagebreak, since this is a rare but possible case.

I also have to admit, that the macro could have more "intelligence" like recognizing two macro calls within a page and then putting both names into the footer, but for this question the pagebreak problem is the only thing I am interested in.

Comment: Try \def\responsible#1{\pagebreak[3]\ifoot{#1}}

Comment: @JohnKormylo Your solution would of course be possible, but then there would be a page break every time `\responsible` occurs.

Note: For the specific case that is given in the second MWE `\def\responsible#1{\pagebreak[3]\ifoot{#1}}` does not work, but `\def\responsible#1{\pagebreak[4]\ifoot{#1}}`does.

Nevertheless, if I am using `\responsible` somewhere in the middle of a page, a page break occurs and gets things even worse than before.

Comment: btw, package `scrpage2` is deprecated and was superceeded by `scrlayer-scrpage`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This approach, using `everypage`, concatenates all the `\responsible`s into the footer in a comma separated list.  Upon each page break, only the last invocation of responsible is retained going into the next page.

In order to meet the needs of the OP, I also introduce a macro `\Newresponsible{}` to wipe the slate clean and not carry over the prior list of names.

One of the issues cited by the OP was a desire to delay the activation of a `\responsible{}` invocation until the next paragraph.  This request addresses the issue of when `\responsible` is invoked at a page boundary, it would apply the name to the prior page, instead of just at the new page.  I consider my fix for this issue something of a kludge, requiring two parts.

1. I typeset a `~\par` and then negative `\vspace` in order to undo the `\baselineskip+\parskip` (**kludge alert!**); and
2. I redefine `\par` to make the change to `\@responsible` at the next `\par` invocation.

This MWE shows several features.  It provides a `\responsible` on page 1.  It then provides a `\Newresponsible` at the page 1/2 boundary to show that the page 1 responsible is not carried over to page 2 and that the page 2 responsible is not pre-listed on page 1.  And it also provides two `\responsibles` on page 2, so that one can see that only the final `\responsible` is carried over to page 3.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{everypage}
% Footer Package
\usepackage{scrpage2}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
% Clear footer and header
\clearscrheadfoot
% Define \responsible and set footer
\makeatletter
\def\@responsible{}
    \let\svpar\par
    \def\responsible#1{~\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}%
      \def\par{~%
        \if\relax\@responsible\relax%
          \xdef\@responsible{#1}%
        \else%
          \xdef\@responsible{\@responsible,\ #1}%
        \fi
        \xdef\@futureresponsible{#1}%
        \let\par\svpar% 
        \svpar%
      }%
    }
\AddEverypageHook{%
  \xdef\current@responsible{\@responsible}%
  \ifoot{\current@responsible}%
  \xdef\@responsible{\@futureresponsible}%
}
\def\Newresponsible#1{\responsible{#1}\AddThispageHook{\gdef\@responsible{}}}
\makeatother

% For test texts
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
% Set author
\responsible{My Name}
\blindtext\blindtext \blindtext
\blindtext
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede.
Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat.
Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent
blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

\Newresponsible{Name 2}%
\blindtext

\responsible{Name 3}%
\blindtext[6]
\end{document}
```

page 1 footer:

[image]

page 2 footer:

[image]

page 3 footer:

[image]

Comment: Wow! That's a nice solution. I will definetely be able to add this to my document(s). It might sound a bit annoying, but I still want to know if it's possible to tie the `\responsible` macro to the following paragraph, since your solution takes care of the names in the footer but still executes the second responsible on the first page instead of the second.

Comment: @SimonM.Laube Please see my addendum code.  Let me know if does what you desire, that is, delaying the redefinition of `@responsible` until the next `\par` invocation.

Comment: Thank you for your efforts. The additional code doesn't seem to work, though. I'm still getting two names on the first page.

Comment: @SimonM.Laube  I think I better understand the problem you mean.  Let me think on it more.

Comment: If it helps you: I've asked this question with a specific MWE, because there I noticed the problem (first). Nevertheless I think that the question might sound a bit unclear. Basically, I want to "connect" a random TeX macro to the following macro or text -- like an unbreakable space (~), but without the space.
Does this sound logical?

Comment: @SimonM.Laube I think the problem isn't that the space is breakable, but somehow related to TeX's paragraph-setting/page-breaking algorithm.  Something to the effect of: TeX tries to set the paragraph on the current page, until it discovers that it must move it to the next page.  But by then, the `\@responsible` has already been redefined.  I'm still thinking.

Comment: Well, this could be a possible reason too. I'm wondering if TeX changes its current mode to shift the paragraph to the next page. If so, a solution could be to catch the mode-change before redefining `\@responsible`. I have to admit that I am not 100% confident with TeX itself since I started to know this wonderful program just about three years ago and got more interested just about a year ago.

Comment: This, `\def\@responsible{}
    \let\svpar\par
    \def\responsible#1{~\par\vspace{\dimexpr-\baselineskip-\parskip}%
      \def\par{~%
        \if\relax\@responsible\relax%
          \xdef\@responsible{#1}%
        \else%
          \xdef\@responsible{\@responsible,\ #1}%
        \fi
        \xdef\@futureresponsible{#1}%
        \let\par\svpar% 
        \svpar%
      }%
    }` works in the sense that it delays the invocation of Name2 until the 2nd page.  However, in this case, Name1 is carried over from the first page.

Comment: You can compensate for the above mentioned behavior with `\def\Newresponsible#1{\responsible{#1}\AddThispageHook{\gdef\@responsible{}}}` and use `\Newresponsible{name}` to start a clean slate, but that is less than automated.

Comment: I think your last `\responsible` solution fits my needs nearly perfectly. Am I understanding your definition right: `\dimexpr` contains all the vspaces that where inserted between the previous paragraph and the next call of `\responsible`. The thing you do next is subtracting the automatically added parskip and baselineskip to get a vertical space of zero between `\responsible` and the following paragraph. Thus, they should always be moved together. The code after that action just does the same as mentioned earlier in this post.

Comment: @SimonM.Laube  Yes, that is how it works.  I don't like solutions that rely on `\vspace`, but it seemed the only way to make it work.

Comment: Thank you very much! Probably I'm able to fix the problem with the first name being put on the second page by myself. I suggest that you edit your answer, so it can be used as the definitive answer for this question, since I can't see another way to tie macros to text. Your answer is already marked as _the correct answer_, so I have nothing more to say than thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

The only sure way to tell what page you are on is to use the aux file.  However, to force \responsible to not occur until the second page you must use \ignorespaces or remove the \par (blank line) between it and the text.

It is possible that \listfooter will work with standard footer packages.  I haven't tried it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% Footer Package
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{everypage}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mylabel}[2]% #1 = label name, #2 = text for \ref
{\protected@write\@auxout{}{\string\newlabel{#1}{{#2}{\thepage}}}}

\newcounter{responsible}
\newcounter{irresponsible}
\setcounter{irresponsible}{1}

\newcommand{\smartfooter}%
{\raisebox{\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight-\footskip}[0pt][0pt]{\rlap{%
  \ifodd\c@page\hspace{\oddsidemargin}\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\listfooter\hfill\thepage}%
  \else\hspace{\evensidemargin}\makebox[\textwidth][l]{\thepage\hfill\listfooter}%
  \fi}}
}%

\newcommand{\listfooter}{\ifnum\c@responsible=0\relax
  \else
    \ifnum\c@irresponsible=\c@responsible
      \ref{author:\theresponsible}%
    \else\ifnum\c@page=\pageref{author:\theresponsible}\relax
      \stepcounter{irresponsible}%
      \fi
    \ref{author:\theirresponsible}%
  \fi
\fi}

\AddEverypageHook{\smartfooter}
\makeatother

% Define \responsible and set footer
\newcommand*{\responsible}[1]{\pagebreak[3]\stepcounter{responsible}\mylabel{author:\theresponsible}{#1}}

% For test texts
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{everypage}

\begin{document}
% Set author
\responsible{My Name}
\blindtext\blindtext \blindtext
\blindtext
Donec ullamcorper, felis non sodales commodo, lectus velit ultrices augue, a dignissim nibh
lectus placerat pede.
Vivamus nunc nunc, molestie ut, ultricies vel, semper in, velit.
Ut porttitor. Praesent in sapien. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing
elit. Duis fringilla tristique neque. Sed interdum libero ut metus. Pellentesque placerat.
Nam rutrum augue a leo. Morbi sed elit sit amet ante lobortis sollicitudin. Praesent
blandit blandit mauris. Praesent lectus tellus, aliquet aliquam, luctus a, egestas a,
turpis. Mauris lacinia lorem sit amet ipsum. Nunc quis urna dictum turpis accumsan
semper.

% Does not work 
\responsible{My Name 2}% \ignorespaces here or in the definition also does not work
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I will consider this solution when improving the macro. Unfortunately this still doesn't solve my problem, namely how to tie the macro to a following paragraph.

Comment: I revised the approach to use the aux file, assuming only one author per page.